# Finding the value of $S$ given a matrix with $81$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we have $81$ positive integers that form a $9 \times 9$ matrix so that the first row forms an arithmetic sequence and every column forms a geometric sequence with the same common ratio. If $a_{2,4} = 1, a_{4,2} = \frac18, a_{4,3} = \frac{3}{16},$ find the value of $S = a_{1,1} + a_{1,2} + \ldots + a_{9,9}.$

Comment: What have you tried? What is $a_{4,1}$? What is $a_{4,4}$? How do you continue from there?

Comment: write a formula for a general arithmetic sequence, and a formula for a general geometric sequence. Plug one formula into the other to get a formula which would give you the $i,j$th entry in your matrix. Then you have 3 known values so set up a system of equations to solve for the unknowns, and then finally use that equation to solve for S.

Comment: @PTDS: That’s just the sum of the first row; $S$ is the sum of all $81$ numbers.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott You are right. However, still it is a non-integer solution.

Comment: @PTDS: Oh, absolutely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a_{1,5} = x$, the common difference of the arithmetic sequence be $d$ and the common ratio of the geometric sequence be $r$

Given: $a_{2,4} = 1, a_{4,2} = \frac{1}{8}, a_{4,3} = \frac{3}{16}$

Or, $$(x-d)r = 1$$ $$(x-3d)r^3 = \frac{1}{8}$$ $$(x-2d)r^3 = \frac{3}{16}$$

Solving the above system, we have $$x = \frac{5}{2}, d = \frac{1}{2}, r = \frac{1}{2}$$ (Since $x > 0$, we disregard the negative values...)

$$S = \sum_{i=1}^9 \sum_{j=1}^9 a_{i, j} = \left[\sum_{k = 0}^8 \frac{1}{2^k} \right] \left[\sum_{j=1}^9 a_{1, j} \right] = \frac{511}{256} \cdot\frac{45}{2} = \frac{22995}{512} \approx 44.912$$

Answer (score -1):

Let, the first entry $a_{11}=a$. Then the first row is $a, a+d, a+2d,...a+8d$.

Now, let $r$ be the common ratio for each column.

Then, the $i^{th}$ column looks like $$(a+ (i-1)d),(a+ (i-1)d)r,...,(a+ (i-1)d)r^8$$.

Therefore for the given values three equations arrive :
$$ (a+d)r^3 = \frac{1}{8} \\
   (a+2d)r^3 = \frac{3}{16} \\
   (a+3d)r = 1
$$

Now subtracting the first equation from the second equation gives $$ dr^3 = \frac{1}{16}
$$

As the entries are integers therefore $d= \frac{1}{2} = r$.

Which gives $ a= \frac{1}{2}$.

Now see that $$ S = \sum_{i=0}^8 \sum_{j=0}^8 (a+id) r^j \\
=  (9a+36d) \frac{1-r^9}{1-r} 
$$.